# Filtering values to be replaced by their column indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I have access to an HDF5 database and have imported data from it.  This data has 2 indexes, date and position.  Suppose after initial modifications the DataFrame is in this structure, with date indexes along the columns and depths along the rows.

```
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+......+--------------+
| -- |  2014-01-01 |  2014-01-02  |  2014-01-03  | .... |  2014-04-10  |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+......+--------------+
| 1m |     10.9    |     15.6     |     10.3     | .... |     9.90     |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+......+--------------+
| 2m |     10.7    |     15.4     |     10.5     | .... |     10.1     |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+......+--------------+
| 3m |     10.5    |     15.2     |     10.7     | .... |     10.3     |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+......+--------------+
| 4m |     10.3    |     15.0     |     10.9     | .... |     10.5     |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+......+--------------+
| 5m |     10.1    |     14.8     |     11.1     | .... |     10.7     |
+----+-------------+--------------+--------------+......+--------------+
```

What I would like to do next is make a table which holds the date with the minimum value for each depth.  With the visible data in the above table, the new table should hold these values:

```
+----+-------------+
| 1m |  2014-04-10 |
+----+-------------+
| 2m |  2014-04-10 |
+----+-------------+
| 3m |  2014-04-10 |
+----+-------------+
| 4m |  2014-01-01 |
+----+-------------+
| 5m |  2014-01-01 |
+----+-------------+
```

After this, I should be able to find the day with the highest number of low values by using the DataFrame.mode() function. This should return *2014-04-10*.

My current attempts at solving this have not given the desired result. I am an amateur with pandas and **my main dilemma is replacing values with their column indexes**.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Using `idxmin`

```
In [1092]: df.idxmin(axis=1)
Out[1092]:
1m    2014-04-10
2m    2014-04-10
3m    2014-04-10
4m    2014-01-01
5m    2014-01-01
dtype: object

In [1093]: df
Out[1093]:
    2014-01-01  2014-01-02  2014-01-03  2014-04-10
1m        10.9        15.6        10.3         9.9
2m        10.7        15.4        10.5        10.1
3m        10.5        15.2        10.7        10.3
4m        10.3        15.0        10.9        10.5
5m        10.1        14.8        11.1        10.7
```

And, if your depth isn't the index, you could use `set_index`

```
In [1107]: df
Out[1107]:
  depth  2014-01-01  2014-01-02  2014-01-03  2014-04-10
0    1m        10.9        15.6        10.3         9.9
1    2m        10.7        15.4        10.5        10.1
2    3m        10.5        15.2        10.7        10.3
3    4m        10.3        15.0        10.9        10.5
4    5m        10.1        14.8        11.1        10.7

In [1108]: df.set_index('depth').idxmin(axis=1)
Out[1108]:
depth
1m    2014-04-10
2m    2014-04-10
3m    2014-04-10
4m    2014-01-01
5m    2014-01-01
dtype: object
```

Comment: Nice answer!  +1

Comment: Thanks! That seems like it will work perfectly! Suppose I do not have the column depth named depth. Is there a way I can modify the column to have that name?